# Command Line Tools on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: terminal, macos, xcode

Okay, I have a problem with my Mac OS X 10.7.5 because I have to learn to program, I was programming "Hello world" and I was using the terminal and "Sublime Text" for text editor but my terminal doesn't execute the function because it doesn't have the command tools, and I searched command tools for my Mac and I found "XCode" but it is for Mac 10.8 What do you recommend for what the "Terminal" execute the functions?

Comment: programming in what language?

Comment: Programming in C language and my Mac is 10.7.5

Comment: Have you tried using the Apple Developer downloads page?

Comment: Create an or use your AppleID and log into [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/download), search for "command line tools" and download and install the latest compatible Command Line Tools (OS X Lion) for Xcode  published April 12, 2013 and/or Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: Although if learning you might find graphic x code better than command line even if experienced code debugger is easier than command line.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr
open terminal and paste `xcode-select --install`

In general, you don't need whole XCode suite ;)